# Listview builder using with future builder with data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to use FutureBuilder to build some LisTiles with ListView.builder. The data is from Firestore.
It looks like the FutureBuilder dont access the ConnectionState.done, because I have this whole time CircularProgressIndicator() showing.

```
 var qn;
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getChargingHistory() async {
    await users
        .doc('$currentUser')
        .collection('chargingHistory')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      qn = querySnapshot;
      qn.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc['Endzeit']);
      });
    });
    setState(() {

    });
    return qn;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Hero(
            tag: 'logo',
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/rz_bildmarke_meyer-technik_rgb.png',
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [],
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 4,
        ),
        body: BackgroundContainer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: getChargingHistory(),
                    builder: (context, querySnapshot) {
                      if (querySnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.done) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: qn.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                  title: Text('${qn.docs.data['Endzeit'].toString()}'));
                              //Text(doc['Endzeit']);
                            }
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                    }),
              ),
```

Comment: do you get your request response from print function?

Comment: @Jahidul Islam yes, when I use this one : `qn.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc['Endzeit']);
      });` I get what I am looking for, but I cant manage to get it with ListView.builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are mixing `async/await` with `.then`. You don't need `var qn;`, simply return the result of `await` from your `getChargingHistory`, like:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> getChargingHistory() async {
    return await users
        .doc('$currentUser')
        .collection('chargingHistory')
        .get();
  }
```

Second, you have to use `index` in `itemBuilder` to get the data for the current `ListTile`. Try:

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
        return ListTile(title:
            Text('${querySnapshot
                .docs[index]['Endzeit'].toString()}'));
```

Comment: Thzank you very much! I actually needed to store the return of future in variable, I dont know why I am not able to use `querySnapshot.docs.length`. But its totally fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `querySnapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done`, try using `querySnapshot.hasData==true`.